# Spring Batch Integration config using Java DSL

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-dsl

The [Spring Integration Java DSL Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) and [Spring Batch Java Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#javaConfig) documentation show how to use Java Configuration for Spring Integration and Spring Batch.

But they dont show how to configure it for the Spring Batch Integration. How is a JobLaunchingGateway configured using DSL?

Cheers,
Menno

Comment: I created a very simple example here: https://github.com/pakmans/spring-batch-integration-example (I know the question is old, but I post here for anyone struggling with this... like me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JobLaunchingGateway` is a `MessageHandler` so you would define it as a `@Bean` and use it in a `.handle()` method in the flow.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I've only used integration gateways for generating proxies for my interfaces, so didn't realise I could just use it as a message handler.

Answer (score 0):

Gary is correct.  You can see a demo of the java config version of this in my webinar on Spring Batch 3.0:

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHCPppMlylY
Code: https://github.com/mminella/SpringBatchWebinar

The SpringBatchIntegration module of that project is what will interest you.