# Spring Batch Integration using Java DSL / launching jobs

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I've a working spring boot/batch projet containing 2 jobs.

I'm now trying to add Integration to poll files from a remote SFTP using only java configuration / java DSL, and then launch a job.

The file polling is working but I've no idea on how to launch a Job in my flow, despite reading these links :

[Spring Batch Integration config using Java DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614059/spring-batch-integration-config-using-java-dsl)

and

[Spring Batch Integration job-launching-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770377/spring-batch-integration-job-launching-gateway)

some code snippets:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory SftpSessionFactory()
    {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sftpSessionFactory.setHost("myip");
        sftpSessionFactory.setPort(22);
        sftpSessionFactory.setUser("user");
        sftpSessionFactory.setPrivateKey(new FileSystemResource("path to my key"));

    return sftpSessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(SftpSessionFactory())
            .deleteRemoteFiles(Boolean.FALSE)
            .preserveTimestamp(Boolean.TRUE)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(Boolean.TRUE)
            .remoteDirectory("remote dir")
            .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
            .localDirectory(new File("C:/sftp/")),
                e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter").poller(Pollers.fixedRate(600000)))
        .handle("FileMessageToJobRequest","toRequest")
        // what to put next to process the jobRequest ?
```

For .handle("FileMessageToJobRequest","toRequest") I use the one described here http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html

I would appreciate any help on that, many thanks.

**EDIT** after Gary comment
I've added, it doesn't compile -of course- because I don't understand how the request is propagated :

```
.handle("FileMessageToJobRequest","toRequest")
.handle(jobLaunchingGw())
.get();
}

@Bean
public MessageHandler jobLaunchingGw() {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher());
}

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Bean
public JobExecution jobLauncher(JobLaunchRequest req) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(req.getJob(), req.getJobParameters());
    return execution;
}
```

I've found a way to launch a job using a @ServiceActivator and adding this to my flow but I'm not sure it's good practice :

```
 .handle("lauchBatchService", "launch")

@Component("lauchBatchService")
public class LaunchBatchService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LaunchBatchService.class);

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@ServiceActivator
public JobExecution launch(JobLaunchRequest req) throws JobExecutionException {

    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(req.getJob(), req.getJobParameters());

    return execution;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .handle(jobLaunchingGw())
    // handle result

...

@Bean
public MessageHandler jobLaunchingGw() {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher());
}
```

where `jobLauncher()` is the `JobLauncher` bean.

**EDIT**

Your service activator is doing about the same as the JLG; it uses [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchingMessageHandler.java#L46).

Your jobLauncher `@Bean` is wrong.

`@Bean`s are definitions; they don't do runtime stuff like this

```
@Bean
public JobExecution jobLauncher(JobLaunchRequest req) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(req.getJob(), req.getJobParameters());
    return execution;
}
```

Since you are already autowiring a `JobLauncher`, just use that.

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Bean
public MessageHandler jobLaunchingGw() {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I still don't get how to pass parameters. how should I implement the jobLauncher bean ? I've edited my initial post.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary, this is awesome I've a very basic flow working now. Pointing that my activator was doing the same and the link to JobLaunchingMessageHandler helped a lot to understand few things.